# Getting the text content from a tinyMCE table

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have a table in my tinyMCE editor and i want to select and copy the text content in the below fashion.
[image: My_Table]

If i select and copy 'one and two' from the table, i should get the text as,
 "one two".

if i copy all the table contents, i should get the text as,
"one    two 
 three  four"

is there any way i can get this done ?
i tried with ed.getContent({format: 'text'}), but it is returning all the contents from the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get just the current selection (as opposed to all of the editor's content) you need to use the selection API to do that.

For example:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getContent({format: 'text'});
```

...or...

```
editor.selection.getContent({format: 'text'});
```